# Auto correlation barely changes

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, recurrent-neural-network

so I'm trying to create an ARIMA model. I need to look at the autocorrelation plot but when I calculated it, I noticed that it barely changes. For example, I get 0.96 for each lag value from 1 to 10.

These are the first 5 values of the series:
4.216, 5.360, 5.374, 5.388, 3.666

The autocorrelation for lag= 1 to 5:
0.96801714, 0.96801539, 0.96801165, 0.96800666, 0.96800327

I used the function "autocorr" in the pandas library to calculate the autocorrelation.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series you are looking at is likely non-stationary. If your series is non-stationary, the ACF will decline very slowly, sometimes being almost constant. The ACF really only makes sense for a stationary series. This means your series has a trend or seasonality in it that you will have to remove before looking at the ACF.

Comment: I doubt seasonality could be behind an almost flat, almost unit ACF, while trend could be.